# Highlight row as long as it doesn't contain A and B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, operators, conditional-formatting

In Microsoft Excel (Office365), I'm having an issue understanding how to highlight a row based on excluding data.

I have a table that looks like the following (looks like StackOverflow doesn't support tables):

- Headers: Customer, "other headers"
- Customer Data Ex.1: "Customer 123" - 'primary customer'
- Customer Data Ex.2: ". .  Customer 123a" - 'sub-customer'

Main Goal: Highlight all rows where:

- There is a primary customer (a primary customer doesn't have ". .")
- The customer cell doesn't contain ". ."
- The customer cell isn't empty

In particular, I'm having an issue excluding rows that contain  ". .".

Using conditional formatting, I added a new row that looks similar to this: =AND($A2<>"",COUNTIF($A2,". .*"))

- This currently gives me a highlight around all "sub-customers", which isn't what I want.

What I want to do is highlight every row that isn't "" or start with ". ." (which would allow me to highlight just the 'primary customer' rows), but I'm missing something about substrings and I can't seem to find an answer on Google or Stack.

Example of expected output:
[image]

Any help would be Greatly Appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please can you show an example of desired output through screenshot or otherwise? It quite unclear right now. Also, your `COUNTIF` doesn't have any reference to what should the count be/not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying your current rule, try:

```
=AND($A2<>"",COUNTIF($A2,". .*")=0)
```

or perhaps

```
=AND($A2<>"",LEFT($A2,3)<>". .")
```